# Update to Archer Queen during a clan war

Tags: clash-of-clans

I want to start an upgrade on my Archer Queen during a Clan War, but need her to attack in the war. Will the Archer Queen function during a clan war while being upgraded?

Answer (score 4):

No, Heroes are not usable in *any* circumstance when they are being upgraded, and this includes the Archer Queen. If you want to use your Archer Queen during a war while she is being upgraded, you will have to speed up the upgrade time either by using a [Magic Item](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Magic_Items) (either Book of Everything or Book of Heroes or one or more Builder Potions [lasts for 1 hour and speeds up upgrade time by 10, so you effectively save 9 hours], or a Hammer of Heroes) or use [Gems](https://clashofclans.fandom.com/wiki/Gems) to instant complete the upgrade.

Note that heroes are not considered buildings however and as such, the Book of Building and Hammer of Building will not work on a Hero's upgrade.

As a side note, the current cost in gems for hero upgrade I believe maxes out at 999 gems for 7 days' upgrade (I can't find a reliable source for that, but my own experience), so if you are planning to use gems, ensure you will have enough.

Comment: Or cancel the upgrade, but I don't think you'd want to do that as you'd have to farm the Dark Elixir to upgrade it again later.